# Возможно ли получить стек текущего процесса или потока?

Tags: c++, c

Для Windows на mingw.
Хотелось бы пройтись по стеку определив адреса функций. Dbghlp не предлагать. Я понимаю что для разных архитектур нуж
ен разный код - ничего страшного.

Я смотрю код одной проприетарной библиотеки, и у них есть разные реализации стек трейсера. Для Г-ну компилятора есть вариант использовать программу addr2line но программе нужны адреса. Как они получают эти адреса в своей библиотеке - тайна.

Реализации с RtlCaptureStackBackTrace и прочими имеются. А как без них сделать, да чтоб ещё и на линуксе работало(у них работает)?
Но это в общем уже другой вопрос.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: если надо не из кода, то любой дампилкой процесса (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump)

Comment: Не работает, видимо нужны pdb файлы.

Comment: @AlexGlebe "Это даст только вершину стека" -  не факт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть [boost::stacktrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html)

```
 std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
```

Для получения информации по функциям есть класс `boost::stacktrace::frame`